Optimal Strategy in Marbles picking game

Two players, say
$A$ and
$B$, play the following game: Both players have
$100$
marbles and may put anywhere between
$1$ and
$100$ marbles in the box each. This decision is not revealed to the other player. Then, they draw
$2$ marbles with replacement between trials. If the marble belongs to
$A$, then assuming that
$A$ put $a$ marbles in the box,
$A$ is paid $100−a$ monetary units from a third party. Similarly if the marble belongs to
$B$, then assuming
$B$ put
$b$ marbles in the box,
$B$ is paid $100−b$ monetary units from a third party. Assume both players play optimally. Find the expected total payout of player $A$.

This is the hint given on the website:
"If the strategy is optimal, then if this game were to be repeated many times, they would not change their strategy. Therefore, the optimal strategy for the game where there are
2 consecutive marble draws is the same as the optimal strategy for the game with one draw. Then, we just multiply the expected profit by
2 to represent the two draws."
Using this, I experimented with various cases and got the expected payout for $A$ in a single draw as $33.5$ and the final answer $67$.
The thing I don't understand is why is the optimal strategy for the game where there are 2 consecutive marble draws the same as the optimal strategy for the game with one draw? Is this something to do with there being replacements after every draws? How would this change for a game with no replacements after draws?

Saying "they draw 2 marbles with replacement" confuses me when it goes on to say "If the marble belongs to A, then ..." and similarly with B.  If the payout is for each of the two marbles (so one of them might win twice, or they might both win once) then each's expected payout is simply double the case of a single draw (the second marble give the same expectation as the first marble) and (assuming utility is linear in winnings) then the same strategy is optimal with two marbles drawn as with one.  This is also the case when drawing without replacement, due to linearity of expectation.

ohh, it makes sense now. Thank you!
